# User agent exceptions override product and CMS pages rules

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5, ui-form

I am trying to implement this dynamic grid/ to add multiple records
it is working fine but I am getting this "User agent exceptions override product and CMS pages rules." all over it any idea how to solve it
[image: Image Output]
code is

```
<fieldset name="multi_answer">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Add Answers</label>
    </settings>
    <container name="multi_ans_holder">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/grid</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">record</item>
                <item name="deleteButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Remove</item>
                <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add New</item>
                <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dndConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record
                    </item>
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="answer_id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="answer">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Answer:</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="answer_author">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Author:</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="answer_status" formElement="checkbox">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">homeslider</item>
                        <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Enable FAQ:</label>
                    <dataScope>answer_status</dataScope>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <checkbox>
                        <settings>
                            <valueMap>
                                <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                                <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                            </valueMap>
                            <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                        </settings>
                    </checkbox>
                </formElements>
            </field>
            <actionDelete>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </actionDelete>
        </container>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the template that I was  using in config:

```
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/grid</item>
```

If we open this template file we can see the html for the warnings and user agent rules. Path for the file:

> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/web/template/dynamic-rows/grid.html

To remove this we can use template from our custom module. Copy the core file grid.html in

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/dynamic-rows

and remove div with class:

`"admin__field-complex-title"`, `"admin__field-complex-content"` and `"messages"`

So "`admin__field-complex`" div will look like this:

```
<div class="admin__field-complex" if="element.addButton">
<div class="admin__field-complex-elements">
    <render args="fallbackResetTpl" if="$data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault"/>
    <button attr="{disabled: disabled}"
            class="action-secondary"
            type="button"
            click="processingAddChild.bind($data, false, false, false)">
        <span translate="addButtonLabel"/>
    </button>
</div></div>
```

Then, specify the path in the config item in your ui_component like this:

```
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/dynamic-rows/grid</item>
```